# How can I add a total row to my code

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this code that I have from a shop system software and wondering how I can add a total row.  I'm a total noob former accountant that is transitioning into data analysis.  I've taken many tutorials and continue to learn, but still a beginner.  Supposedly it's the shop system software databse is based on SQL 2012.  Here's my code, works fine, just need a total row for the last column only:

```
Select  ESTIM.DESCRIP
      , ESTIM.PARTNO
      , ESTIM.PRODCODE
      , ESTIM.QTYONHAND
      , ESTIM.QTYONORDER
      , ESTIM.REORDLEVEL
      , ESTIM.STOCKINGCOST
      , ESTIM.QTYONHAND * ESTIM.STOCKINGCOST As "Total Item Value in Stock"
From    ESTIM
Where   ((ESTIM.PRODCODE Like [ENTER PRODUCT CODE:]))
Order By ESTIM.PARTNO;
```

Comment: Calculate it in another similar query and `UNION` to the original, but remember that the sort order is random, so you would have to add a field which is 0 for all records and 1 for the total, and order by that. But in general, this sort of presentation is better left for the report generators, such as SSRS or Crystal etc.

Answer (score 0):

There's a few ways to get an over all total out of this query.

You could use a UNION query to get a new row with just the total, and all other fields NULL:

```
 SELECT 'TOTAL', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, SUM(ESTIM.QTYONHAND * ESTIM.STOCKINGCOST) FROM ESTIM  WHERE ((ESTIM.PRODCODE Like [ENTER PRODUCT CODE:]));
```

You could add a new field using a windowing function that holds the total (Which will be repeated for each row)

```
Select  ESTIM.DESCRIP
      , ESTIM.PARTNO
      , ESTIM.PRODCODE
      , ESTIM.QTYONHAND
      , ESTIM.QTYONORDER
      , ESTIM.REORDLEVEL
      , ESTIM.STOCKINGCOST
      , ESTIM.QTYONHAND * ESTIM.STOCKINGCOST As "Total Item Value in Stock"
      SUM(ESTIM.QTYONHAND * ESTIM.STOCKINGCOST) OVER (PARTITION BY 1) as "Total of Total Item Value"
From    ESTIM
Where   ((ESTIM.PRODCODE Like [ENTER PRODUCT CODE:]))
Order By ESTIM.PARTNO;
```

You could also... possibly... get crafty with `GROUP BY <fields> WITH ROLLUP`, but I think that would add more records to the output then you are looking for.